# Сломал свою Ubuntu. Не работает sudo

Tags: ubuntu, консоль, sudo

Набираю в консоли sudo и получаю

~$ sudo

sudo: /usr/bin/sudo должен принадлежать пользователю с uid 0 и иметь бит setuid

Я ничего не делал, он само.

Comment: Поэтому я первым делом меняю пароль руту, чего и всем советую.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://ubuntu.fliplinux.com/sudo-usr-lib-sudo-sudoers-so-uid-0.html

И в root написать как предложили выше (chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo && chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo). Это помогло мне. Спасибо всем.

Answer (score 3):

1. Выйти из под пользователя и зайти под рутом. Если у вас графическая оболочка нажмите ctrl+alt+F4
2. Из под рута `chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo && chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo`
3. Перезагрузка

Comment: Если пароля рута нет, то классика с `init=/bin/bash` параметром к ядру, после загрузки перемонтирование `/` в `rw` и дальше уже менять права. Ну и пароль сразу поменять руту.

Comment: @becouse что-то не получилось. После нескольких попыток перезагрузки и нажатия комбинации ctrl+alt+f4 мне предложили ввести логин и пароль. После чего я прописал указанное Вами во втором пункте, перезагрузил и ничего не изменилось, то же самое

Comment: Ага, попробовал ещё раз, так же ввёл логин и пароль, после чего мне консоль написала: изменение владельца /usr/bin/sudo Операция не позволена. Может когда предлагает ввести логин я должен ввести root?) Но пишет что login incorrect...